# jQuery toggle out issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, selector

I have an issue with one of the sites I'm working in where the jquery selector:

```
$('a[title]').click(...)
```

only gets called when within the site's root.

When you click on the navigation at the top of the page, the div flashes in and content is loaded via AJAX, and when you close it and try to reopen, the selector doesn't get called.

EDIT:
This is where the navigation links get created:

```
<a title="unternehmen" href="http://cheloufi.com/enoi_v2/">Unternehmen</a>
<a title="leistungen" href="http://cheloufi.com/enoi_v2/leistungen/">Leistungen</a>
<a title="information" href="http://cheloufi.com/enoi_v2/information/">Information</a>
```

Also note that even though the href attribute is "http://cheloufi.com/enoi_v2/", when you click on the link, the site redirects to "http://cheloufi.com/enoi_v2/#/enoi_v2/".

Then for the div to roll out:

```
$('a[title]').on('click', function() {

    if(contentState==0){                                                                                    //check content state                                                                                                                               

      contentOpen();                                                                                        //open content

      $('#toggleBut').css({backgroundPosition:'0px -40px'});

      contentState = 1;                                                                                     //indicate content is open

    }else{

      contentClose();   

     $('#toggleBut').css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'});

      contentState = 0;

    }
});
```

However, that method only gets called the first time you click on the link, not on any consecutive times.

Also, this is a modified WordPress theme, if that makes any difference.

Has anyone run into a problem like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers - your `click` handler will only be attached to elements which are **present in the DOM upon page load**

```
$(document).on('click', 'your_selector', function() {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: I see. However, the links aren't loaded dynamically. They are there always. It's the content div that gets loaded dynamically. The navigation links don't change at all.

Comment: Ahh I see.. I didn't actually visit the link you posted I just (wrongly) assumed that would be the issue from what you were describing. Could you post some code in the question? I'm reluctant to click links to external sites, plus it would benefit others if there was some code within the question itself, cheers!

Comment: I've added (what I think is) the root of the problem

Answer (score 0):

should be

`$('a[title]').on('click', function() {alert('my function here')})`
or
`$('body').on('click', 'a[title]', function() {alert('my function here')})`

to attach event handlers to new content

EDIT

this is how your site looks like to me

[image: site]

is that the problem you are talking about?
because the content was always loaded for me, but outside my screen.

Comment: THe issue is if you click on the "+" button, the content will hide (on the left), but then if you click on one of the navigation links again, the content doesn't open. It only works on the first instance you click on a link. Hope this makes it a little clearer.

Comment: Also, the site shouldn't look like that, I'm not sure what the problem is there.